# How many commentaries have there been of the Vishnu Purana?

Tags: translation-request, vishnu-purana, resource

I would like to have the list of commentators of the Vishnu Purana. How many of these commentaries have being translated to English? Are any of the commentaries available online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Srimad Bhagavatam has the greatest number of commentaries of any Purana.  Still, I know of two commentaries on the Vishnu Purana:

1. Sridharan Swami's Atma Prakasha, written from the viewpoint of Shuddhadvaita.  You can read it in Sanskrit [here](https://archive.org/details/vishnupuranasvaprakash).
2. Engalalwan's Vishnuchittiyam, written from the viewpoint of Vishistadvaita.  You can read it in Sanskrit [here](https://archive.org/details/VishnuPuranaWithVishnuchittiyamPBAnnangaracharya1972).

Unfortunately, neither of them have been translated into English.

Comment: Is there any reason a purana needs a commentary? They appear to be quite straightforward without hidden meaning or terse statements. Honestly curious about it.

Comment: @user1952500 Well, the Puranas do have various philosophical statements in them, so for those commentaries can help you understand them.  For instance, Prahlada's hymn to Vishnu in the Vishnu Purana has Vedantic content as I discuss here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7770/36

Comment: The link of Atma Prakash doesn't contain Sanskrit comm. It's in some other lang.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sridhara Swami's Atmaprakasha eddited by Pandit Thaneshchandra
   Upreti and published by: Parimal Publications, Delhi, India is
   available in 2 volumes in Sanskrit. [Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/vp_vol1) and [Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/vp_vol2)
2. [Vishnu Purana with Vishnuchittiyam](https://archive.org/details/Vishnu_Purana_with_Vishnuchittiyam_-_PB_Annangaracharya_1972/page/n1) commentary by Vishnuchitta
       Alwar (also known as Engalalvan), edited by PB Annangaracharya and
       published in Sanskrit in 1972 from Kanchipuram.