# How does Sri Madhvacharya interpret Srimad-Bhagavatam 12.5.11?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, dvaita

Shukdeva advises Raja Parikshit in Srimad-Bhagavatam (12/5/11):

> *aham brahma param dhaam brahma aham paramam padam/evam samikshya cha aatmanam aatmanimaadhaya nishkale*
>
> **English Translation**: **Think: I am Brahman**, the Absolute Abode, the final destination and attach the Self to the ever-unstinted Brahman.

**Interestingly, Sukadeva at the end of Bhagavatam does not advise King Parikshit to pray to God for liberation. He advises to think: I am Brahman.**

**How does the Sri Madhvacharya interpret the above sloka?**

Comment: While I dont know how dvaitins interpret this, it is interesting to note that in the upanishads, it is stated that "aham" is one of the names of brahman.

Comment: You may just write non advaitins... Else, dvaitins only represent Tattva vada followers of Madhvacharya...

Comment: If you know Sanskrit, you can search for Madhvacharya's interpretation here: https://archive.org/details/SriBhagavataTatparyaNirnayaEBook

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury yes the link finally worked & i hv dwnlded.Thnx

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I found that only some verses are commented by Madhvacharya or the book is an incomplete version?

Comment: @Pandya I don't think it's an incomplete version...

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Right, I think Madhvacharya hasn't commented on this verse

Comment: There is no conflict in interpertation aham is Braham. its not saying im brahman.. if you replace God Name with Aham there is no conflit aham is gods name is already stated by sriman madvacharya already

Answer (score 4):

**The dvaita interpretation of this verse is that it reflects the highest meditative state of a devotee, who is in deep love and knowledge of Brahman as it comes very close and intimate with Brahman.** The statement "I am Brahman" is made because the devotee thinks of nothing but Brahman.

vijayadhvajatIrtha was a later dvaita commentator on the bhAgavatam in his padaratnAvalI. It says [the following](https://archive.org/details/SrimadBhagavatamCanto12withMultipleSanskritCommentaries/page/n131/mode/2up) on 12.5.11.

> दंशदोषास्पर्शने प्रकारान्तरेणोपायमाह-अहमिति । न हन्यत इत्यहं न हीयत इति वा कदापि न जहाति स्वशक्तिमिति वा एवं विधमीश्वरं विहाय कदापि न तिष्टत्यस्वातन्त्र्यादित्यर्थः उपासनाफलमाह-एवमिति । एवंविधस्त्वं निष्कले आत्मनि परमात्मानं समाधाय संयुज्य समीक्ष्य सम्यक् ध्यायन्

I have kept the Devanagari text above because it is my own transcription, so should be checked. Here is my attempt at translating it:

> daMshadoShAsparshane prakArAntareNopAyamAha-ahamiti
>
> daMsha- sting , doShA- night , sparshane- feel, prakArAn- section, tare- boat crossing, pAyam- water, Aha- no, aham- I am, iti- that
>
> **The feeling of a sting at night, partly crossing the water, aha, I am that.**

I am a little unsure about how to translate this sentence of commentary. The writer compares himself to a sting, signifying the baseness of the self in contrast to the idea that it becomes Brahman, and only having partly crossed the ocean of samsAra: the same word tari is used for crossing samsAra in the [ganga sahasranAma #400](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423767.html). For the dvaitin, the self is insignificant compared to Brahman, like a mosquito to a person. This statement contrasts with the view that is contradicted in the next sentence.

> na hanyata ityahaM na hIyata iti vA kadApi na jahAti svashaktimiti vA evaM vidhamIshvaraM vihAya kadApi na tiShTatyasvAtantryAdityarthaH upAsanAphalamAha-evamiti
>
> na- no, hanyata- kill, ity- thus, ahaM- I, na- not, hIyata- extinguished, iti- that, vA- or, kadApi- never, na- no, jahAti- leaves, svashaktim- own power, iti- that, vA- or, evaM- such, vidham- kind, IshavaraM- god, vihAya- having left, kadApi- never, na- no, tiShTa- constant, tya- roaming, svA- self, tantry- by tantra, Aditya- deity , arthaH- object of desire, upAsanA- worship, phalam- reward acc, Aha- not, evam- like, iti- this
>
> **Thus that self (“I”) is not killed; that is never extinguished or leaves its own power, or never becomes like a kind of god, having left. No, the reward for worship is not like this: [becoming a] constantly roaming self, deity [and] object of desire using tantra.**

So the dvaita interpretation of this verse is that the self always remains after liberation, not being deified.

> evaMvidhastvaM niShkale Atmani paramAtmAnaM samAdhAya saMyujya samIkShya samyak dhyAyan
>
> evaM- such, vidha- kind, tvam- you, niShkale- undivided, Atmani- in the soul, paramAtmAnaM- who is the supersoul, samAdh- having focused, Aya- thus, saMyujya- intimacy, samIkShya- having investigated, samyak- wholly, dhyAyan- lost in meditation
>
> **In such a kind of undivided soul, you having focused [ on the one who is] the supersoul, thus [there is] intimacy, having investigated wholly and [being] lost in meditation.**

Answer (score 0):

Srimad Bhagavatam 12.5.11
aham brahma param dhaam brahma aham paramam padam/evam samikshya cha aatmanam aatmanimaadhaya nishkale
I dont think Sripada Madhvacharya commented on this verse.
According to my studies I learnt this verse meant that both atma and paramatma are qualitatively same whereas quantitatively different for example : A drop in the ocean is qualitalively same as the ocean whereas quantitatively not same. Even in the vishnu purana
Vishnu purana 5 Ansha 33 Adyaya sloka 47-49 lord krishna says something similar but still atma and paramatma are different.

Hare krishna
Jai Sri Radhe

Comment: OP asked from Dwaitha perspective. Not Achintya Bhed Abhed

Answer (score 0):

In brahma Sutra3.3.46 there is a type of devotion known as so'ham bhakti meditating oneself as god.
SB(12.5.11):
aham brahma param dhaam brahma aham paramam padam/evam samikshya cha aatmanam aatmanimaadhaya nishkale

Gopala Tapini Upanishad states that meditating on god form is devotion.
Henceforth even the above quotation is in favour of devotion only.
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34937/21339v has a very relevant answer regarding this question.

Thank you

Hare Krishna