How does Hinduism explain existence of dinosaurs before humans?
How does Hinduism explain existence of dinosaurs before humans?
Didnt time start with satya yuga with humans?
Were animals created before humans?
I read a gita verse which said roughly "In beginning Bramha created humans and taught them to sacrifice and said be thou happy"
So how does hinduism explain existence of dinosaurs before humans?

This may answer the question -  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57731/31356

Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/do-hindu-scriptures-acknowledge-the-presence-of-dinosaurs

Hindu sense of time is very deep - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manvantara
In Durga Shaptshati (Devi Bhagwat) there is mention of 2nd Manvantar incident.
Currently we are in 7th Manvantar.
Take Dinosaur theory lightly. It's mostly based on extra-polation, which is far away from exactness.

But fossil evidences do show the existence of dinosaurs before humans

I replied for "before human" assumption of this question.
